# String issue in nodejs POST API

Tags: node.js, string, api

I have nodejs API. it is accepting inputs and based on that input it is running sql query.

```
 var userdata={
    "msisdn":reqdata.accessInfo.endUserId,
    "service_code":reqdata.charge.serviceIdentifier,
       "code":reqdata.charge.code,
    "gtrid":resdata.serverReferenceCode 
  };
```

in that above parameters, if is send the data like above then my query is not accepting that value. If i hot code the value then it is working as expected.

```
value is: '5017331301541065138607061'
```

please let me know how to solve this issue. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use as below.

```
var mystring=JSON.stringify(resdata.serverReferenceCode);
  mystring=mystring.replace(/["']/g, "");
```

use mystring variable where ever required.